# Заблокировать через .htaccess доступ к одноименным файлам директорий

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Есть папка *plugins* а в ней папки плагинов например *myplugin1*, *myplugin2* и т.д. В каждой папке плагина есть одноименный php-файл [т.е. в папке *myplugin1* есть файл *myplugin1.php*], а также файл *admin.php* и могут быть еще другие файлы.

```
plugins
  - myplugin1
    - myplugin1.php
    - admin.php
  - myplugin2
    - myplugin2.php
    - admin.php
    - ajax.php
```

Нужно заблокировать через .htaccess прямой доступ к каждому файлу плагина, название которого совпадает с названием его папки, а также к файлу *admin.php* но к остальным файлам доступ оставить. Т.е. в папке например *myplugin2* заблокировать *myplugin2.php* и *admin.php* но прямой доступ к *ajax.php* оставить.

Доступ ко всем *admin.php* заблокировал вот так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*)/admin\.php$ - [F,NC]
```

Но как заблокировать одноименные файлы плагинов не знаю, подскажите. Или может сразу один паттерн на все "одноименные" файлы и admin.php

Вот что сейчас есть в моем .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
ServerSignature Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule config.php - [F]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*)/admin\.php$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: @Visman поправьте в своём, я сам это тока что экспериментально выяснил :)

Comment: А, это ваш коммент был) В общем и ваш вариант почему то перестал работать. Зато это работает:`RewriteRule ^plugins/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.php$ - [F,NC]`

Comment: здесь же никакой проверки на одноименность

Comment: Да, точно, ajax.php тоже блокирует(

Comment: Тестеру, конечно, доверять нельзя, но всё-таки, там больше похоже на правду - http://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=7b546e99-39ac-536f-bdce-7d0d4ce4abda